# Python: json -> text, how to only write unique values?

Tags: python, json, file

I have a json file, from which I'm extracting quotes. It's the file from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/akmittal/quotes-dataset) (formatted exactly the same way).

My goal is to extract all the quotes (just the quotes, not the authors or other metadata) into a simple text document. The first 5 lines would be:

```
# Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.
# I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle me at my worst, then you sure as hell don't deserve me at my best.
# Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.
# Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.
# Be who you are and say what you feel, because those who mind don't matter, and those who matter don't mind.
```

The challenge is that some quotes repeat and I only want to write each quote once. What's a good way to only write down unique values into a text doc?

The best i came up with was this:

```
import json

with open('quotes.json', 'r') as json_f:
    data = json.load(json_f)

    quote_list = []

    with open('quotes.txt', 'w') as text_f:
        for quote_object in data:
            quote = quote_object['Quote']
            if quote not in quote_list:
                text_f.write(f'{quote}\n')
                quote_list.append(quote)
```

But it feels grossly inefficient to have to create and maintain a separate list with 40,000 values.

I tried reading the file on each iteration of the write function, but somehow read always comes back empty:

```
with open('quotes.json', 'r') as json_f:
    data = json.load(json_f)

    with open('quotes.txt', 'w+') as text_f:
        for quote_object in data:
            quote = quote_object['Quote']

            print(text_f.read()) # prints nothing?
            # if it can't read the doc, I can't check if quote already there

            text_f.write(f'{quote}\n')
```

Would love to understand why text_f.read() comes back empty, and what's a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can use a set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set:

```
import json

with open('quotes.json', 'r') as json_f:
    data = json.load(json_f)

    quotes = set()

    with open('quotes.txt', 'w') as text_f:
        for quote_object in data:
            quote = quote_object['Quote']
            quotes.add(quote)
```

Adding the same quote to the set multiple times will have no effect: only a single object is kept!

Comment: It's probably better than what I had, but I'm not sure it solves the problem. You still need to loop over the set on each quote iteration (in you're code you're missing the write part and hence the looping part), which still feels inefficient. I wonder if there's a way to check the file you're writing to directly, and if that would be a better way? Maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: Wait I'm an idiot. I realized that iterating over a set is O(1), whereas iterating over a list is O(n). You are correct. This is super efficient. Thank you!